# Can't use Windows Hello on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, biometrics

The 'Set up' button in 'Fingerprint' section is inactive. I enabled **Use biometrics** and **Use Windows Hello for Business** in GPO, but no luck
[image: Screenshot]
I think it's because I do not have a PIN, but I can't set it, because I don't see such an option

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up passport and deploy certificates too. Follow the Microsoft documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-azureadjoin-passport-deployment

The steps are going to be different depending on if you are using Azure AD or if you have your own Domain Controller.

If the guide I posted doesn't help you will need to do more research and come back with more details about your set-up.

Comment: You really should quote and cite all relevant information from your link

Comment: It's pages of information with pictures. The answer is RTFM. This is a process and not a simple switch.

Comment: 99% of questions here involve a process which is answered with a picture.  The point of providing the relevant information in the body of your answer, is to prevent link-rot.  I will reverse my downvote when you improve your answer.

Comment: I don't use either AD or Domain Controller, what i should do then?

Comment: @sashok724, Windows Hello for Business is designed to work in a business environment with a domain controller. Either set up your corporate network as Microsoft intended or use normal Windows Hello for Windows 10.

Comment: I want to use normal Windows Hello, but i can't because the button is inactive